# Jquery die() doesn't unbind the event already bound with live()

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery 1.8.0 in my project with struts2.  I am using jquery live() to bind the click event to all existing element and all future element dynamically added by ajax. I am calling die() against the target element each time the page is loaded before calling live() on the target element but in my case die() doesn't unbind the event handler already bonud with target element. The problem is  event handler for click event attached with particular target element as much as time the page is loaded. So the event fires multiple times. Please help me to find the solution.

Here is my code:

```
<sj:a href="#" cssClass="edit fileShareClass" id="cont_%{#id}"  cssStyle="color: #334c6e;text-decoration:none;" >Share</sj:a> 



 jQuery(function ($) {
 $('.fileShareClass').die('click');
$('.fileShareClass').live('click',function (e) {
    e=$(this);
    var shareToContactId=$(e).attr('id').split('_')[1];


     $.get("./file_share.action?shareType=multiple&folderId=0&fromPage=listContactPage&shareToContactId="+shareToContactId, function(data){
        $('#fileShareDiv').empty();
        $('#fileShareDiv').append(data);
    }); 


});
});
```

also tried with on() and off() like below

```
       jQuery(function ($) {

       $(document).off('click','.fileShareClass');
       $(document).on('click','.fileShareClass',function (e) {
        e=$(this);
       var shareToContactId=$(e).attr('id').split('_')[1];


       $.get("./file_share.action?shareType=multiple&folderId=0&fromPage=listContactPage&shareToContactId="+shareToContactId, function(data){
        $('#fileShareDiv').empty();
        $('#fileShareDiv').append(data);
    }); 


});
});
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the code in question?

Comment: @Erin please go thorough my code and give me a solution

Answer (score 2):

use `.on()` and `.off()` -

As of jQuery 1.7  `.live()` and `.die()` are depricated

see [offical docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Yeah. But i tried with on() and off() & delegate() and undelegate() where all cases, still it's firing the event multiple times and also tried with <sj:head jqueryui="true" ajaxcache="false"/>. All the way it's not working.

Comment: @BabuPasungily - in your code you set .off() first , which does nothing because nothing has been attached yet, then you call on() .  You have to call .off() after .on() if you want to remove the click handler